# Pytest patch fixture not resetting between test functions when using return_value

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, pytest-mock

I have a issue with one of my fixtures, which is doing a patch not resetting between test calls.

The fixture is basically a patch which is wrapper around a object, so I can assert that it has been passed into another function.

The fixture looks like this:

```py
@pytest.fixture
def mock_entities(mocker: MockFixture) -> MagicMock:
    entities = Entities()
    namespace = f"{__name__}.{Entities.__name__}"
    return mocker.patch(namespace, return_value=entities)
```

`Entities` is a class that I want to patch, but I want it to function completely like the original, due to the fact that it has `property` methods, as well as using `__len__`. It is declared in the body of a function and the reason I need it mocked is because I'm passing it into another function and I want to assert that it has been passed in correctly. I originally tried "wraps=`, but I wasn't able to get that to work correctly.

Full test code below:

```py
import pytest
from pytest_mock import MockFixture
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, PropertyMock
from typing import List
from pprint import pprint
from unittest.mock import patch

class Entities:

    _entities: List[dict] = []

    def __init__(self, entities: List[dict] = []):
        self._entities = entities

    @property
    def entities(self) -> List[dict]:
        return self._entities

    @entities.setter
    def entities(self, value: List[dict]):
        self._entities = value

    def append(self, value: dict):
        self._entities.append(value)

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self._entities)

class ApiClient:

    def get_values(self) -> List[dict]:
        # We get values from a API with a pager mechanism here
        pass

class EntitiesCacheClient:

    def get_values(self) -> Entities:
        # We get values from cache here
        pass

    def set_values(sel, values: Entities):
        # We set values to cache here
        pass

class EntityDataSource:

    _api_client: ApiClient = None
    _cache_client: EntitiesCacheClient = None

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._api_client = ApiClient()
        self._cache_client = EntitiesCacheClient()

    def get_entities(self) -> Entities:

        entities = self._get_entities_from_cache()
        if entities:
            return entities

        # I want to mock Entities, so that I can assert that it is passed in to the EntitiesCacheClient.set_values()
        entities = Entities()
        api_values = 1 
        while api_values:
            api_values = self._api_client.get_values()
            if not api_values:
                break

            for values in api_values:
                entities.append(values)

        if entities:
            self._save_entities_to_cache(entities)

        return entities

    def _get_entities_from_cache(self) -> Entities:
        return self._cache_client.get_values()

    def _save_entities_to_cache(self, entities: Entities):
        self._cache_client.set_values(entities)


@pytest.fixture
def mock_entities_cache_client(mocker: MockFixture) -> MagicMock:
    namespace = f"{__name__}.{EntitiesCacheClient.__name__}"
    return mocker.patch(namespace, autospec=True).return_value

@pytest.fixture
def mock_api_client(mocker: MockFixture) -> MagicMock:
    namespace = f"{__name__}.{ApiClient.__name__}"
    return mocker.patch(namespace, autospec=True).return_value

@pytest.fixture
def mock_entities(mocker: MockFixture) -> MagicMock:
    entities = Entities()
    namespace = f"{__name__}.{Entities.__name__}"
    return mocker.patch(namespace, return_value=entities)

def test_entity_data_source_entities(mock_entities_cache_client, mock_api_client, mock_entities):

    mock_entities_cache_client.get_values.return_value = None

    expected_entity_1 = {"id": 1, "data": "Hello"}
    expected_entity_2 = {"id": 2, "data": "World"}

    expected_entities_list = [
        expected_entity_1, expected_entity_2
    ]

    mock_api_client.get_values.side_effect = [
        [
            expected_entity_1,
            expected_entity_2,
        ],
        []
    ]

    entity_data_source = EntityDataSource()
    result: Entities = entity_data_source.get_entities()

    mock_entities_cache_client.set_values.assert_called_once_with(mock_entities.return_value)

    assert len(result.entities) == len(expected_entities_list)
    assert result.entities == expected_entities_list

def test_entity_data_source_entities_more_results(mock_entities_cache_client, mock_api_client, mock_entities):

    mock_entities_cache_client.get_values.return_value = None

    expected_entity_1 = {"id": 1, "data": "Hello"}
    expected_entity_2 = {"id": 2, "data": "World"}
    expected_entity_3 = {"id": 3, "data": "How"}
    expected_entity_4 = {"id": 4, "data": "Are"}
    expected_entity_5 = {"id": 5, "data": "You"}
    expected_entity_6 = {"id": 6, "data": "Doing?"}

    expected_entities_list = [
        expected_entity_1, expected_entity_2, expected_entity_3,
        expected_entity_4, expected_entity_5, expected_entity_6
    ]

    mock_api_client.get_values.side_effect = [
        [
            expected_entity_1,
            expected_entity_2,
            expected_entity_3,
            expected_entity_4,
            expected_entity_5,
        ],
        [expected_entity_6],
        []
    ]

    entity_data_source = EntityDataSource()
    result: Entities = entity_data_source.get_entities()

    mock_entities_cache_client.set_values.assert_called_once_with(mock_entities.return_value)

    assert len(result.entities) == len(expected_entities_list)
    assert result.entities == expected_entities_list
```

On the second test method, the fixture is patching `Entities` and it has a `return_value=Entities()` (basically). However, the fixture/mock seems to retain the original `Entities` from the first test, meaning that it already has 2 records inside the `_entities`, resulting in a total of 8 records and not the 6 it should have.

```
>       assert len(result.entities) == len(expected_entities_list)
E       assert 8 == 6
E         -8
E         +6
```

Why is this happening? I thought when using the `pyest-mock` and the `mocker` fixture, there would be no need to reset the mocks as it takes care of that for you

https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mock/

> This plugin provides a mocker fixture which is a thin-wrapper around the patching API provided by the mock package. Besides undoing the mocking automatically after the end of the test, it also provides other nice utilities such as `spy` and `stub`, and uses pytest introspection when comparing calls.

Does this not extend to the objects assigned to `return_value`? How am I supposed to be mocking `Entities` if this is not the correct way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have been a victim of the common pitfull of [mutable default arguments](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html). Each time you set the `entities` property you in fact change the default value of the `entities` argument, so the next time a new `Entities` object will be created with an empty argument, this will be used instead of an empty list.

The usual fix is to use a non-mutable placeholder object as default value:

```py
    def __init__(self, entities: List[dict] = None):
        self._entities = entities or []
```

If you are interested in the reasons for this design decision, you can check these related questions:

- ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)
- [Good uses for mutable function argument default values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9158294/good-uses-for-mutable-function-argument-default-values)

Comment: This is actually by design?

Comment: Yes. Default arguments are stored with the function object at load time and not recreated at runtime.

Comment: I added links to a couple of related questions.